# combine files based on similar ID in the middle

Tags: bash

```
01_002_H10_S190_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz
01_002_H10_S190_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
01_002_H11_S191_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz
01_002_H11_S191_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

I want to merge to and to files that have similar ID based on the letter and two numbers **H10, H11** etc. All the files have ID of 1 letter followed by to numbers. Also, the string before **H10,H11** is always **01_002_**

I have a bash script to combine files, but not sure how to get the two files that belong together (XXXX in my skript below.

```
declare -A ids for f in XXXXXXXX; do   ids[${f%%_*}]=1;done
```

out

```
01_002_H10.fastq.gz
01_002_H11.fastq.gz
```

Comment: How do you want to merge the files? AFAIK you can't just concatenate them, they would have to be decompressed and then recompressed

Comment: The script that I have attached works for combining them. Its just about gettin the correct IDs.

Comment: What are *"to and to"* files please? `L00` is also one letter and two digits, so is `S19`, so how do I know which one matters? What do you mean by *"merge"* - alternate lines, concatenate, time order?

Answer (score 0):

This returns all names seperated by newlines:

```
find . -printf "%f\n" | egrep -o "^01_002_[A-Z0-9]+" | sort | uniq
```

You can integrate it like this:

```
for f in $(find . -printf "%f\n" | egrep -o "^01_002_[A-Z0-9]+" | sort | uniq);
```